# Mongoose date difference

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose

i want to get values in between two dates. in the database the dates are formatted as "MM-DD-YYYY" and below please find the query.

**ASSIGNED_DATE : { $gte : "01-01-2017", $lt : "01-03-2017" }**

the above query is working and when i pass dates as in between two years, then it will not return values. like below

**ASSIGNED_DATE : { $gte : "12-29-2016", $lt : "01-03-2017" }**

please help me to figure out this.

Comment: you should try save date as dates instead of string for date comparison to work. You can always format them to show it to the front end.

Comment: Please are there any other suggestions other than that ?

Comment: are your dates saved as strings in the database? In that case it's impossible to compare dates because you actually compare just characters.

Comment: Why don't you run a `patch` on collection to update all `ASSIGNED_DATE` values converting into `ISODate(value)`. Then everything will comes into control.

Comment: Jyothi Babu Araja, that's what i've planned to do next. is it possible to update all my ASSIGNED_DATE values into ISODate(value) using one query ? if so please add your comments. much appreciated